# Copy certain files from folder - and give each file a date-stamp

Tags: powershell, file, copy

I have a script that look for specific filenames, and copy those to another destination.
No problem here, what I need help with is to give each file a _date/time in the destinationfolder

Like the copied file file1 get the name file1_20220427

The script I have now is like below:

```
$search_folder = "H:\SOURCE"
$destination_folder = "H:\DEST"
$file_list =  @("file1","file2")
foreach ($file in $file_list) 
{
$file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder  | % { $_.FullName}
if ($file_to_move) 
{
    Copy-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
}
}
```

Comment: Well, what should the date be? The date that it was moved?

Comment: Hi, yes, like Get.Date() - I just dont know how to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying too much of your code, there isn't a need for a `foreach` loop as you can pipe directly to `Copy-Item`:

```sh
$search_folder      = "H:\SOURCE\*"
$destination_folder = "H:\DEST\"
$file_list          =  "file1*","file2*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Include $file_list -File|
    Copy-Item -Destination { 
        $destination_folder +  ($_.BaseName + "_" + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + $_.Extension)  
    }
```

This is doable since `Copy-Item` can accept a scriptblock where you can modify the destination path to include a concatenated result. All that's needed is to provide the destination path, the *basename* property to keep the beginning of the name, append the date in format of `yyyMMdd`, and the extension to keep the file type.

Also, take note of the use of `-Include`. This parameter can accept an array of names to search for where you would need to provide the full name (*extension included*), or part of it with a wildcard (*asterisk -`*`*) allowing us to get rid of the `foreach` statement.

- The only issue when using `-Include` is that it's *PowerShell's* solution to providing a search filter and not a file system provider based one.
- Therefore, the source *path* has to include an asterisk at the end of the folder path, or the use of `-Recurse` is needed.

Now, your file names should reflect `file1_20220427`,`file2_20220427` and so on accordingly, in your destination folder.

**EDIT**: based on your question in the comments, you can just test against the path to see if a folder with that days date is there, create the folder if not, then just route the items there now instead; it will copy the item's there if it already exists as well.

```
$search_folder      = "H:\SOURCE\*"
$destination_folder = "H:\DEST\"
$file_list          =  "file1*","file2*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Include $file_list -File |
    Copy-Item -Destination { 
        $dateFormat = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        $destPath   = Join-Path -Path $destination_folder -ChildPath $dateFormat 
            if (-not(Test-Path -LiteralPath $dateFormat)) { New-Item -Path $destPath -ItemType "Directory" | Out-Null }
        "$destPath\" +  ($_.BaseName + "_" + $dateFormat  + $_.Extension)  
    }
```

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to extend this so it also creates a folder with todays date - and then put the files into that folder?

Comment: @HenrikRosqvist, what is the folder creation based off of? When should it move the files? Which files should it move? Based on what?

Comment: Hi
This script shall run 1 time every night - it copies some files from the source folder - and puts them in the destination folder. To get some structure it would be nice if this script before copying the files - created a folder in the destination folder with todays date - and copies the files to that folder. Next night, it will run again , and create a new folder with thats days date - and put the files in that folder.

Comment: @HenrikRosqvist, see last edit at the bottom.